# Combine separate column/rows as one column/row in R

Tags: r, read.table

using `txt.file`, i have this dataset:

```
                                   Xenopsylla cheopis    Echinolaelaps sp.      
Maxomys rajah                         1                    3                                                      
Callosciurus prevostii borneensis     4                    2
```

using this function,

```
test<-read.table("data.txt",header=T)
              Xenopsylla   cheopis    Echinolaelaps   sp.      
Maxomys        rajah         1            3                                                      
Callosciurus   prevostii   borneensis     4            2
```

R seems to recognize my data as different columns/rows and produce this error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 2 did not have 4 elements
```

i tried to use `textConnection` but it seems that it does not produce what i want

Comment: read.table will separate columns based on spaces unless otherwise specified.  Without seeing the file: "file.txt" it will be difficult trying to help.

Comment: This is because the second organism has an extra space in the name compared with the first. What separates the columns in the text file? If it's tab-delimited, you can try adding `, sep = "\t"` to `read.table`.

Comment: Can you share your dataset or a reduced version of your dataset so we can see more easily what is going wrong?

Comment: This is the link of the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9pn6z7l2y1muef/file.txt?dl=0 @Dave2e

Comment: This is the link of the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9pn6z7l2y1muef/file.txt?dl=0 @Ouistiti

Comment: I edited my answer. It will work for you now as you can see. Please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the validate symbol next to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) @Ouistiti

Comment: May i know what is the function of ([[:lower:]])([[:space:]])([[:lower:]])? Is it related to columns and rows? or the spaces between sentences? As far as i read, this character string is to replace the occurrence of pattern. Can you explain more since i couldnt find any resourceful website. What if i have 100 columns and 50 rows, the function is still the same? @Ouistiti

Comment: @NurElfieyraSyazana I explain it in a new edit to my answer I wrote for you. Your problem was just that you had blank spaces issues and that made it impossible for R to read your .txt file properly. I got rid of the problematic spaces. 

Could you please accept my answer by clicking on the symbol below the number next to my answer?

Comment: I see you are working on biological/ecological data. I highly recommend you take a look at the workshops from the QCBS if you want to learn R and statistical analysis in a biological/ecological framework.
http://qcbs.ca/wiki/r

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation. It helps me, a lot. Cheers! @Ouistiti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all just store your data in a character vector as I did here:

```
test<-readChar("C:/Users/Julian/Downloads/file.txt", file.info("C:/Users/Julian/Downloads/file.txt")$size)
```

Obviously, you need to replace the path of my file with yours.
Then you get rid of the space between Genus and Species using `gsub()`

```
test<-gsub("([[:lower:]])([[:space:]])([[:lower:]])", "\\1\\3",test)
```

Finally, you can read your data using `read.table()` with the `text` argument:

```
 a<-read.table(text=test,sep="\t",header=TRUE,row.names = 1)
 a

                                Xenopsyllacheopis Echinolaelapssp. Ixodessp.
Maxomysrajah                                    3                8         9
Callosciurusprevostiiborneensis                 5                7         1
Sundamysmuelleri                                3                5         7
Niviventercremoriventer                         6                8         9
```

**EDIT:**
To answer OP's new question in the comments:

```
"([[:lower:]])([[:space:]])([[:lower:]])"
```

enables us to find all the parts of the strings that we created with `readChar()` that match this pattern. This pattern is: a lowercase letter followed by a blank space followed by a lowercase letter.

You can understand this match the genus and species name but not a species name and the following genus because a genus starts with an uppercase letter.

Now the `"\\1\\3"` part means that we keep the first and third part of our 
`"([[:lower:]])([[:space:]])([[:lower:]])"` pattern. That is `([[:lower:]])` and `([[:lower:]])`. Because there is no space between `"\\1` and `\\3` in `"\\1\\3"` we will join them without spaces. Therefore we will have Genusspecies instead of Genus species.